# Bot Framework & IntentPattern: How to use the options?

Tags: botframework

Microsoft provides the [following example of an IntentPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-dialog/adaptive-dialog-prebuilt-recognizers?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#regexrecognizer):

```
                new IntentPattern()
                {
                    Intent = "AddIntent",
                    Pattern = "(?i)(?:add|create) .*(?:to-do|todo|task)(?: )?(?:named (?<title>.*))?"
                },
```

Now, if I want to run a dialog based on this intent, how can I pass the "title" from the intent's pattern as an option to the new dialog?

So given the following trigger:

```
        Triggers.Add(new OnIntent("AddIntent", actions: new List<Dialog>()
        {
            new BeginDialog(nameof(MySecondaryDialog), options: ??)
        }));
```

And the user types: "add todo named testing", how can I pass the "testing" as an option to the MySecondaryDialog?

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I didn't find a solution to this.